# how fork() can return multiple values?

Tags: c, fork

How does the `fork()` function return different values in parent process and child process?

Assume there is no write operation in parent process and its child process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207656/how-is-it-possible-for-fork-to-return-two-values/4207670

Comment: It is unclear whether this question asks about the two values (see `man 3 fork` on your system), or about exactly how this is done internally ("_How_ does...") and how `fork()` is implemented.  The assumption at the end does not seem to be relevant to the question.

Answer (score -1):

There is no requirement for either the parent or the child to place any pid into the other's memory.

At the moment the fork occurs, the kernel has the task of duplicating the whole process space of the parent (which might be achieved without a complete copy, for example by duplicating page table entries initially unto some memory gets written).

The kernel, during any system call, is able to pass a return value from the call by fixing up the user process stack before it returns it to user mode. That's where all return values from system calls come from.

It is absolutely no problem for the kernel to fix up the two stack frames with different values for the parent and the child. Neither process cal be executing, they are both in a system call so the stack frame is well-defined, and the kernel can access all memory.

Comment: The return value is typically stored in a register, not on the stack, *e.g.* in `rax` on x86-64.

Comment: @StephenKitt  Thanks for the reminder. The ABI uses a compendium of the stack and registers, but I felt the simplest answer was the better level here.

Comment: I wouldn’t want to come across as pedantic, but the simplest answer is that `fork`’s return value is stored in a register. See [`man syscall`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) which has a table listing all the various return value storages used on the architectures supported by Linux.